# api laravel not update table update mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

when I go to update the values on the db are not changed and the test fails

i have the following diagram on the mysql db:

```
   public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('polls', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->integer('idPollEx')->nullable();
                $table->text('param');
                $table->enum('status', ['a', 'b', 'c','d'])->default('a');
            });
        }
```

Feature/exampleTest.php

```
 $requestSvr1 = [
                "idPollEx" => 1,
                "op" => ["k", "z", "y"]
            ];

 $response = $this->put('/api/update',$requestSvr1);

 //get value elaborate by pull
 $dataDbTest = $this->get('/api/');


 //check field process_status == processing
 $this->assertSame('b',$dataDbTest[0]['status']);
```

PollsController.php

```
public function pull(Request $requestSvr1)
    {
        //get data
        $requestSvr1 = $requestSvr1->all(); 

        //order
        $query= DB::table('polls')->whereIn('k', $requestSvr1['op'])->limit(1)->get();

        //assignment of values
        $query->update(['idPollEx' => $requestSvr1['idPollEx']]);
        $query->update(['update' => 'k']);
        $query->update(['status' => 'b']);
        return response()->json($query, 200); 
    }
```

Comment: you can not `DB::table('polls')->whereIn('k', $requestSvr1['op'])->limit(1)->get();` this if you want to update the object in the database later.

Comment: where do you have a field named `k`?

Comment: you can see $requestSvr1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code here is just database query, it is not laravel eloquent ORM.

```php
$query= DB::table('polls')->whereIn('k', $requestSvr1['op'])->limit(1)->get();
```

So, you need to use like this:

```php
$poll = Poll::whereIn('k', $requestSvr1->op)->first();

$poll->status = 'b';

$poll->idPollEx = $requestSvr1->idPollEx;

$poll->save();
```

```php
class Poll extends Model { protected $fillable=[ 'param', 'status', 'idPollEx' ]; }
```

Comment: class Poll extends Model
{
   protected $fillable=[
        'param',
        'status'
    ];

}

Answer (score 0):

check your $fillable properties in model

Comment: I tried to put fillable = [] but the fields are not updated anyway

Comment: you should put columns that can be updated using Model::Update({'array_of_columns'}) that has been set as $fillable property in model